# NAT traversal  from known public server programmatically

Tags: java, proxy, ssh, nat, tunnel

I have already done some research about NAT traversal, and got some suggestions from the web about the P2P applications. But my case is somewhat different than one traditional P2P applications.I already have one public Server, i just need to access the devices behind NAT from the known public Server.

The detail info about my case is as following:

```
1.PC-A have public IP
2.PC-B is behind NAT, does not have public IP. In my case PC-A and PC-B is under full control.
3.PC-C is also behind NAT, and could be reached from PC-B
```

The question is that:

1. Is there any way so that i could build a tunnel between the public server PC-A and PC-B, so that i could reach PC-C from PC-A with TCP protocol(or even UDP)?
2. It's worth noting that all should be done programmatically, especially in Java.Is there any library could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PC-A is often called a 'relay' in P2P talk.

The basic principle is that all peers behind firewalls (PC-B and PC-C in your case) establish *outbound* connections to PC-A. PC-A then "links/bonds" the connections.
Usually these connections are made over HTTP, which is firewall friendly. So for PC-B to talk to PC-C, a simplified sequence is:

- PC-B and PC-C both establish an HTTP connection to PC-A
- PC-B signals to PC-A that it wants to send data to PC-C
- PC-B sends its data to PC-A on the outbound request
- PC-A forwards the data to PC-C on the synchronous response.

Things get (very) complicated when you throw in

- authentication
- security
- redundant relays
- connection timeouts, reliability, recovery, etc...

Most P2P frameworks implement some kind of relays. This is the case for JXTA and XMPP (check ICE).

I believe Ian Mc Ginniss also developed something called HTTP Tunnel as part of the Netty project (originally as replacement for JXTA relays which are somewhat sub-optimals)

Comment: @ BGR, i'm sorry that i missed the part that i have no control on the PC-C, so PC-C will not establish an HTTP connection to PC-A or even PC-B.In my case the relay function should be on PC-B.

Comment: @ BGR, another thing need to be addressed is that i want to access PC-C via Generic TCP Port, ie. i could SSH or Telent etc to PC-C from PC-A.

Comment: OK. Then have PC-B works as a "reverse" relay and establish outbound connections to both PC-A and PC-C. Then have PC-A use the response channel to send data to PC-C via PC-B.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Generic TCP port". Ports and protocols are two different matters even though 22 is often used for ssh, 80 for HTTP, etc... You can have an SSH client/server (see SSH Mina for a Java implementation) running on PC-A/PC-C if you do not want to handle HTTP requests.

Comment: The relay only sees bytes going though and binds connections; it does not care about the protocol used between the two endpoints. Usually, you use HTTP to connect the relay to the endpoints and "wrap" the protocol used between the endpoint within the HTTP requests/responses

Comment: @ BGR, i have already tried SSH remote port forwarding with OpenSSH, it seems work. Just on PC-B execute "ssh -R 2001:PC-C:22 ubuntu@PC-A". In this way, i could access different port 22 on PC-C from PC-A port 2001. But when i try to use Apache MINA SSHD as embedded SSH server on PC-A,the remote port forwarding will show error "remote port forwarding  failed for listen port 2001".I have checked that port 2001 is not used by other process.

Comment: @ BGR, could you kindly check my java code as [link](http://pastebin.com/czPH0mVK). I have tried both on Windows or Linux as PC-A, but both failed with same error message.

Comment: Things I would try: put a big try/catch-all around your main to see if you get any errors starting the Mina sshd server, make sure it runs by telneting from PC-B to PC-A on the sshd server port, use a port above 1024 for your sshd server (you need to run as root otherwise on your Linux machine)

Comment: @ BGR, i have figured it out.To my shame, i forgot to enable port forwarding for Apache SSHD via "sshd.setForwardingFilter(new BogusForwardingFilter());". Thanks you so much~

Comment: @ BGR, one thing to be confirmed is that TCP forward via remote SSH port forwarding is reliable on the Internet? In my case, PC-A is on the Internet, while PC-B,PC-C located at Customer locations.

Comment: It is reliable. We use ssh tunnels in prod with success. It is also easy to script under linux automatic re-creation of the tunnel if you loose it.

Comment: @ BGR, did you use embedded SSH server such as Apache SSHD or just use OpenSSH? I'm not sure whether we could mange OpenSSH programatically in Java.

Comment: We use both OpenSSH and Mina SSHd as servers and OpenSSH for SSH tunnels